# What is the most popular data access pattern to work with MSEF todate?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

What is the most popular data access pattern to work with MSEF? This is because I am going to adopt that pattern.

In case of NHibernate Repository is the most popular one as far as i know.

What is the case of EF?

Comment: this is very subjective. maybe you should reword your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the **most** popular pattern is, but a very popular one would be Repository (as well). It separates the logic that retrieves and maps the data to the entity model from the business logic that acts on the model. The business logic becomes agnostic to the type of data that comprises your data source layer.

You can find a nice example of how to implement it [here on the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx).

I think the 'unit of work' pattern would be a good a alternative. Or perhaps you can try a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Repository" pattern that provides a set of methods returning IQueryable<> result. Here is an example of possible interface (one of the simplest cases): http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/should-my-repository-expose-iqueryable.html
Implementation example: http://russelleast.wordpress.com/2008/09/20/implementing-the-repository-and-finder-patterns/

What I want to add comparing to other answers: you need to decouple your repositories from business logic. This will easier significantly unit testing of you BLL.

Answer (score 0):

**Unit of Work** and **Repository**.
You can google for **FabrikamShipping** - reference implementation of saas app using them.